# Why i can't transform this set back to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

```
x = ['Book1', 'Book2', 'Book3', 'Book4', 'Book5', 'Book6']
p = ['Book1', 'Book3']
x.pop(x.index('Book2'))
print(x)
print(type(x))
```

Here i get the x without Book2, and type is list, just as expected.

```
x = set(x) - set(p)
list(x)
print(x)
print(type(x))
```

Here i my output is :

> {'Book4', 'Book5', 'Book6'}
>
> class 'set'

Why `x` doesn't get transformed back to a list ?
The objective is to delete from `x` the itens in `p`, i know i can use a list comprehension to do it, but i'm using it for studying propose. After that process, i'm going to append some more items to `x`, thats why i need to to get back to a `list` type, otherwise i get this error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "set") to list

Comment: `x.pop(x.index('Book2'))` could be `x.remove('Book2')`

Comment: Thanks @Chris_Rands just forgot about `remove()`, you are right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`list(x)` is not in place. It converts `x` to a new list and returns a reference to it, so it should be assigned back to `x` (or to anything else):

`x = list(x)`

Compare

```
x = set()
list(x)
print(x)
# set()
```

to

```
x = set()
x = list(x)
print(x)
# []
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't knew about the reference thing

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign your list(x) to your variable

```
x = ['Book1', 'Book2', 'Book3', 'Book4', 'Book5', 'Book6']
p = ['Book1', 'Book3']
x.pop(x.index('Book2'))
print(x)
# ['Book1', 'Book3', 'Book4', 'Book5', 'Book6']
print(type(x))
# <type 'list'>
x = set(x) - set(p)
x = list(x)
print(x)
# ['Book4', 'Book5', 'Book6']
print(type(x))
# <type 'list'>
```